# ValueError with ssl and get certificate

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, certificate

I am trying to retrieve the certificate information from a web site,
someone suggested using `ssl.get_server_certificate('http://google.com')`

I have been running into lots of issues doing anything because I am behind a proxy, I was able to get `requests.get()` to work and also the `ssl.get_server_certificate()`

When I run `import ssl 
 r = ssl.get_server_certificate('http://www.google.com') 
print(r)`

I get an error message of `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this? I am very new to python.

EDIT : after correcting syntax to make host and port inside a tuple, I now get a timeout error from what I assume is my proxy.

```
r = ssl.get_server_certificate(('google.com', 443))

print(r)

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: A certificate is used for HTTPS communications not HTTP ones. So you need to use `https://` URLs...

Comment: It is also expecting a tuple with host and port - `r = ssl.get_server_certificate(('google.com', 443))` returns a cert.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek you're right, I had not realized.
@DaveStSomeWhere now if i run that line I get ```for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed``` I am assuming because I am in a proxy environment

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere just ran the way you did, without the https:// and now have a timeout error. Again assuming its from my proxy.